# Min-max selection sort

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, sorting

Is there already modified version of selection sort that works like this pseudocode:

```
a // the array, index starts at 1 (not zero-based)
n = len(a)
for x in 1 to n
  big = x 
  small = x
  last = n-x+1
  for y in x+1 to last
    if a[big] < a[y] then big = y
    if a[small] > a[y] then small = y
  if big <> small 
    if small <> x then swap(a[small],a[x])
    if big <> last then swap(a[big],a[last])
```

if there is such an algorithm, what is the name of it?

Comment: ah nevermind, it's shaker sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the wikipedia article on selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Variants) states, this variant is called cocktail sort.